# Django Templates: How does it decide where to load a template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I was following the Django Girls Tutorial up to the point where we add the login capabilities and I've gotten to a point where it tries to load from a different template folder than I want.

I have all my blog templates in blog\templates\blog\, etc. and that is where Django is looking for my login.html. However, in the tutorial (and as a result in my folder structures), the path for login.html is: mysite/templates/registration/login.html. So how would I make Django look there?

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will look to your `settings.py` for how to load templates, and the order in which it should try to load templates. It's likely that you haven't configured django to look for templates in mysite/templates.

There's a setting called `TEMPLATE_DIRS` which is a list of absolute paths for your template folders. So in your `settings.py` file, try something like below. Read my comments to see what each line does.

```
# create a variable that stores the absolute path to your project's root directory
# you might have something like this already defined at the top of your settings.py
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir))

# this is the default value for TEMPLATE_LOADERS
# which says to look at the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` variable, and then in each of your app's subdirectories for templates
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = ('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader')

# the special sauce. tell django to look at the "templates" folder
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), )
```